# HDFS Encryption | Remote Exception

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs

I am create encryption zone in HDFS with following command.

```
hdfs crypto -createZone -keyName tes3 -path /user/root/zoneEncr
```

But firing command , i am getting just

```
RemoteException:
```

on screen.

I checked log and got following exception

```
2016-05-06 11:05:07,073 DEBUG PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 62][route: {}->http://localhost:6083][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
2016-05-06 11:05:07,073 ERROR BaseAuditHandler - Error sending message to Solr
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.request(LBHttpSolrClient.java:570)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:131)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:76)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.destination.SolrAuditDestination.log(SolrAuditDestination.java:154)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.provider.BaseAuditHandler.logJSON(BaseAuditHandler.java:172)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditFileSpool.sendEvent(AuditFileSpool.java:890)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditFileSpool.runDoAs(AuditFileSpool.java:838)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditFileSpool$2.run(AuditFileSpool.java:759)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditFileSpool$2.run(AuditFileSpool.java:757)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1637)
        at org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditFileSpool.run(AuditFileSpool.java:765)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://localhost:6083/solr/ranger_audits
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:565)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:214)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.request(LBHttpSolrClient.java:546)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:6083 refused
```

I dont have solr installed so how do i avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding 'nn' user in Ranger.If nn user does not exists then add nn user in Ranger and provide "Get Keys" permission to nn user from keyadmin in Ranger KMS.

If the nn user does not have permissions to get keys, you will not be able to create crypto zones or list crypto keys.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is problem with connection with solr. Either switch off audit to solr or check solr connection.